# string concatenation without using the library function in c?

Tags: c, arrays, concatenation

I am writing code to emulate the strcat function in the c library and I can't pass my first test in main. I was wondering if someone could guide me as to why. here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *strcat(char string1[ ], char string2[ ])
{
    int i;
    int j;


    for(i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; i++);

    for(j=0;string2[j] != '\0';j++)
    {

        string1[i] = string2[j];
        i++;


    }

    string1[i] = '\0';
}



int main() { 
    char str1[81], str2[81]; 
    char again = 'y', newline; 
    while (again == 'y') { 
        printf("Enter a string\n"); 
        scanf("%s", str1); 
        printf("Enter another string\n"); 
        scanf("%s", str2); 
        printf("The concatention is %s\n", strcat(str1, str2)); 
        printf("Second test:  The concatenation is %s\n", str1);
        printf("The second string is still %s\n", str2); 
        printf("Again? (y/n)\n"); 
        scanf("%c%c", &newline, &again); 
    }
}
```

Comment: A return statement would be a good place to start...

Comment: Please take a look at the contract for `strcpy()` in [C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You must return the `string1` is `strcat`.

```
return string1;
```